# Powershell - How to complete/close a zip file in powershell

Tags: powershell, zip

I want to create a zip file in powershell, add items to the zip file, then get the compressed content of that zip file as bytes immediately after the zip file is created, in the same scipt.  The problem is that it does not seem that the zip application has written its contents to the file system.  How does one close/flush the zip application so that the next powershell statement can gain access to the newly created zip file?

Example:

```
new-item -type File test.zip -force
$zip = ( get-item test.zip ).fullname
$app = new-object -com shell.application
$folder = $app.namespace( $zip )
$item = new-item file.txt -itemtype file -value "Mooo" -force
$folder.copyhere( $item.fullname )
dir test.zip # <---- Empty test.zip file
Get-Content -Encoding byte $zip | echo # <-- nothing echoed
```

The "dir test.zip" shows a zip file with no contents, thus the Get-Content returns nothing.

Please note that this seems to be a problem with the asynchronous behavior of the copyhere action.  If I sleep after the copyhere line, the zip file will become populated.  However, I do not know how long one must sleep, nor do I want to delay the processing.

Much Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never created archives from PowerShell, but this doesn't look like it would work at all.

Comment: take a look here: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ . Inoic.zip is a better to working with zip file!

Comment: It does, indeed work.  If you look at the directory in which you execute these statements, you will find that a test.zip file has been created.

Comment: I'd like to not use any third party libraries.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. Which version of powershell and Windows are you using?

Comment: I am using:

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method to zip files is not appropriate for automated scripts. This has limitations in Windows 2003 and Windows xp server for 3 gigs. Also, it does not give proper errors.

Comment: After screwing around with this for a while, I have to agree.  Invoking the shell to manipulate a zip requires a lot of overhead, and is extremely indirect.  I checked out the Inoic.zip library that @Christian mentioned, and found it to work very well for my use case, which is creating the zip file bytes without having to write to the file system.

I thank every one for their creative solutions!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reconsider using a third party library. However, if you must use *copyhere*, try this:

```
new-item -type File test.zip -force
$zip = ( get-item test.zip ).fullname
$app = new-object -com shell.application
$folder = $app.namespace( $zip )
$item = new-item file.txt -itemtype file -value "Mooo" -force
$folder.copyhere( $item.fullname)
while($folder.Items().Item($item.Name) -Eq $null)
{
    start-sleep -seconds 0.01
    write-host "." -nonewline
}
dir test.zip # <---- Empty test.zip file
Get-Content -Encoding byte $zip
```

Comment: If one has to use the shell to create zip files, then this solution works well in determining when the asynchronous copyhere is complete.  Nope that I am still unsure if this method will result in a partial write of the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, all that you need is to wait until zipping operation is not completed. So, i come up with this solution, you should place this code after executing  "$folder.copyhere" or "Copy-ToZip" powerpack cmdlet.

```
    $isCompleted = $false
    $guid = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
    $tmpFileName = $zipFileName + $guid
    # The main idea is to try to rename target ZIP file. If it success then archiving operation is complete.
    while(!$isCompleted)
    {
        start-sleep -seconds 1
        Rename-Item $zipFileName $tmpFileName -ea 0 #Try to rename with suppressing errors
        if (Test-Path $tmpFileName)
        {
            Rename-Item $tmpFileName $zipFileName #Rename it back
            $isCompleted = $true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating the zip empty file like this:

```
$zipfilename = "myzip.zip"
set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
```

Then the rest of your code.

this code in my box works:

```
$zipfilename = "a.zip"
set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
$app = new-object -com shell.application
$zip = ( get-item a.zip ).fullname
$folder = $app.namespace( $zip )
$item = new-item file.txt -itemtype file -value "Mooo" -force
$folder.copyhere( $item.fullname )
```

to get the content of a zip use this:

```
$zipfilename = "myzip.zip"
$shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
$zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)
$zipPackage.Items() | Select Path
```

Comment: I you run my script twice, the second time it runs the test.zip file will already be there, but the results are the same - it will still be empty.

None the less, I tried this with the same results :-(

Comment: In my box (xp pro /powershell 2.0) works: create a myfile.zip and add a file.txt.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me.  I don't want to get the uncompressed contents of the zip file after I create it.  I want to get the actual zip file itself (compressed) in the same script which created it, immediately after I create the zip.  If you run your two scripts together as one (slightly modified to correct for the zip file name), the result is the same - an empty zip file.

Comment: I repeat: in my box the script create the zip file containing the file.txt. Don't know why you can't do it works.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file in a closure, so that the variable goes out of scope and powershell closes the file... if you'd made that part into a subroutine then it would have closed naturally when you returned.

```
new-item -type File test.zip -force
{ 
  $zip = ( get-item test.zip ).fullname
  $app = new-object -com shell.application
  $folder = $app.namespace( $zip )
  $item = new-item file.txt -itemtype file -value "Mooo" -force
  $folder.copyhere( $item.fullname )
}
dir test.zip # <---- Empty test.zip file
Get-Content -Encoding byte $zip
```

Comment: I tried this, but the creation of a closure or placing the code in a function does not improve things.